# Is there a way to condense rows further in a SQL query through grouping on more than one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, grouping, distinct

Below you'll see a SQL query that successfully returns the revenue for a given merchant... unless any of that merchant's invoices happens to have more than one successful transaction. In that case, it will sum each invoice items revenue times its number of successful transactions.

If I wasn't already joining merchants and grouping by merchant.id, I would group by invoices.id

When you give `GROUP BY` multiple columns, it will only group together rows that are the same in both columns, resulting in a table that is less condensed rather than more condensed. Is there a way to run something along the lines of a second group by on this query such that it won't add the revenue any invoice's invoice items more than once?

```
SELECT  merchants.id,
      sum(invoice_items.unit_price * invoice_items.quantity) as total_revenue FROM merchants
  INNER JOIN invoices
    ON invoices.merchant_id = merchants.id
  INNER JOIN invoice_items
    ON invoice_items.invoice_id = invoices.id
  INNER JOIN transactions
    ON transactions.invoice_id = invoices.id
WHERE transactions.result = "success"
  AND merchants.id = ?
GROUP BY merchants.id;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I see nothing in your query rather returns information about items.

Comment: I had started writing about a different query. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a N-to-M relationship that is causing invoices items to be sumed more than once. One solution would be to move the computation of the total per invoice to a subquery :

```
SELECT  merchants.id, invoice_items_total.total_revenue
FROM merchants
  INNER JOIN invoices
    ON invoices.merchant_id = merchants.id
  INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT invoice.id, sum(unit_price * quantity) as total_revenue 
      FROM invoices_item 
      GROUP BY invoice.id 
    ) invoice_items_total ON invoice_items_total.invoice_id = invoices.id
  INNER JOIN transactions
    ON transactions.invoice_id = invoices.id
WHERE transactions.result = "success"
  AND merchants.id = ?
GROUP BY merchants.id;
```